# QGIS 3.6 and known Mac issue

Tags: qgis, mac

I am trying to run QGIS 3.6 on a Mac with the latest OS.

I have the following gdal error message:

```
>>>>>>> gdalwarp -of GTiff -tr 250.00115934006 -250.00168180475995 -tap
>>>>>>> -cutline "/Users/Laura/Documents/2019 Adjusted Maps/CA Base Map
>>>>>>> Dissolved/CACTYBASE7dis.shp" -crop_to_cutline
>> "/Users/Laura/Documents/2019
>>>>>>> Adjusted Maps/NLCD adjusted/NLCDAlbers.tif"
>> "/Users/Laura/Documents/2019
>>>>>>> Adjusted Maps/NLCD adjusted/NLCDClipCA.tif"
>>>>>>>
>>>>>>> GDAL command output:
>>>>>>>
>>>>>>> /bin/sh: gdalwarp: command not found
>>>>>>>
>>>>>>> Execution completed in 0.19 seconds
>>>>>>>
>>>>>>> Loading resulting layers
>>>>>>>
>>>>>>> The following layers were not correctly
>>>>>>> generated.<ul><li>/Users/Laura/Documents/2019 Adjusted Maps/NLCD
>>>>>>> adjusted/NLCDClipCA.tif</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages
>> Panel' in
>>>>>>> QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the
>>>>>>> algorithm.
```

I have applied all the steps found on Kyngchaos.com, but it still isn't working

I think there may be a problem with this pathway but I am unsure which part needs to be fixed. Any suggestions?

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/
Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.4/Programs:
```

Comment: I believe GDAL doesn't like filepaths with spaces in them. (Source: I vaguely remember seeing it mentioned in a comment on GIS SE.) Try outputting directly to the documents folder (`/Users/Laura/Documents`) instead of `/Users/Laura/Documents/2019 Adjusted Maps/NLCD adjusted`. You might also need to move your input files.

Comment: I believe the new installers are better than the old Kyngchaos ones - https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed all file pathways to delete spaces. Now QGIS crashes.

Comment: Do you think there is a problem with this command having a space before "Frameworks"???         
 /Library/ Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/2.3/Programs: